# Android GridView how to occupy the full width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I am using the following `GridView`:

```xml
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Which results to this screen:

[image]

What can i do in order for the photos to occupy the full width of the `GridView` and avoid having this empty space on the right? (marked in red)

Comment: well, your `GridView` already occupies width... problem is in items, which are not fulfilling width of a single cell (so you have black space also between 1 and 2, and 2 and 3) and/or also aren't centered. show your adapter code and single item layout